# Quarkus Integration Tests Run Multiple Times Due To Inheritance

Tags: java, integration-testing, quarkus

We have a project that has two integration classes, Test.java and IT.java. Test.java has the annotation @QuarkusMainTest, IT.java has the annotation @QuarkusMainIntegrationTest above the class declarations and IT.java extends Test.java class.

We have implemented a new feature where the program checks if a file to be generated already exists in the target folder and acts accordingly. We have written some integration tests where files are generated, the feature is used to check their existence and at the end of the integration tests all files and folders get wiped out.

The problem we have encountered is that when the integration tests run, all tests in Test.java pass followed by some tests failing in IT.java. This is because IT.java somehow first runs the parent Test.java tests again and then runs its own tests before wiping, causing unwanted files to be generated and giving wrong results.

The current solution we have is removing the inheritance between the two classes and copy all the tests from Test.java to IT.java. By doing this we do not have the problem anymore but now every integration test needs to be duplicated in the classes.

Are there any alternative solutions to this?

(We tried following this guidelines from the original documentation: https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#quarkus-integration-test)

Comment: What you are seeing it standard JUnit behavior

Comment: Thank you for your reply @geoand, is there a better way of handling this situation? We do not like removing the inheritance but also could not find any other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues, and there are a few things you could try.

### Avoid inheritance between tests

Inheritance is great and eliminates code duplication, and it's usually my first instinct too. I know at least some of the Quarkus quickstarts use inheritance between the `*IT` and `*Test`. However, some people also say it's [an anti-pattern in tests](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/unit-testing/3-reasons-why-we-should-not-use-inheritance-in-our-tests/).

The reasons usually given are that:

- The true goal of inheritance is polymorphism, not code re-use
- Executing all the `@Before` and `@After` methods in a test hierarchy has a performance cost (and, as you've seen, can also lead to undesirable behaviour)
- Having some behaviour in a superclass and some in a subclass can make code harder to read

So what do you do instead of inheritance?

#### JUnit Extension

[One option](https://medium.com/decisionbrain/factor-test-code-the-junit-5-way-that-is-without-inheritance-9ba2784d34) is to write a JUnit extension, but that seems way too much like hard work. It would maybe be appropriate if you needed to repeat lots of assertions, but it's overkill for many use cases.

#### Utility class

A much simpler technique is to just extract your common code into a utility class. This can work, but it doesn't necessarily help readability, you need to remember to invoke the required method on the utility class, and it's not really taking advantage of what Quarkus offers you.

#### Use `QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager`

Quarkus allows you to define [`QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager`](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#quarkus-test-resource) which can be used to start and stop shared services. That might also be useful for the shared filesystem work.

### Use conditions to only run 'destructive' code once

Alternatively, you could take advantage of conditional execution to disable some tests/part of the test classes, and ensure the problematic code only ran once, even with inheritance.

#### Use a `QuarkusTestProfile` as a guard

Quarkus has [an ability](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#writing-a-profile) to define profiles that customise what config and resources tests see. You could define one profile for the subclass, and one profile for the superclass, and then use tags plus command-line arguments to [enable and disable tests](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#running-specific-tests).

For example, you could define a profile as

```
public class MostOfTheTime implements QuarkusTestProfile {
        @Override
        public Set<String> tags() {
            return Collections.singleton("favouritetest");
        }
    }
```

```
@QuarkusTest
@TestProfile(MostOfTheTime.class)
public class MostOfTheTimeTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // test something
    }
}
```

would run most of the time, but if you ran with a environment variable or system property, such as `quarkus.test.profile.tags=nope`, the test would be disabled. The caution is I don't know for sure how this would interact with inheritance and your class hierarchy, so you might end up disabling both tests, rather than just the target one.